# Can I associate console logs with specific test cases in Jest?

Tags: jestjs

I've looked at the work done with jest-circus and the new Reporter handler: onTestCaseResult but it doesn't give me what I need. I want to capture the console logging for each test case to allow for better analysis of errors when running large test suites against other people's API implementations. At present the console logs are only available on the TestResult object in the onTestResult handler but I would need it in the TestCaseResult object.
Thanks